# Can't make the custom DialogFragment transparent over the Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I need to create a dialog over a fragment (that takes up the whole screen). The dialog needs to be a floating dialog that will be positioned over the fragment with the fragment darkened out outside of the fragment..

For the custom Dialog, i have a linearLayout that has curved edges, no matter what i do, the dialog has a black bordering on all sides (very small). I've tried everything to make it transparent and go away (so that all of the dialog is just the linear layout - curved box)

For the DialogFragment, this is what I have for onCreateView

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    LinearLayout layout =(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
    LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout)layout.findViewById(R.id.display_item);
    populateItemData(item, inflater);
    return layout;
}
```

custom_dialog is just a LinearLayout that has android:backgroung set to #000000

This is my style for the custom Dialog

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item> 
    <item name="android:alwaysDrawnWithCache">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

I tried all kinds of combinations in this style (from what I've seen online) and I can't get rid of that annoying black bordering, I can paint it white or any other color if i set that LinearLayout background to anything other than #000000...

I've spent literally 3-4 hours on this, i hope someone else can help out...

Answer (score 355, accepted):

Try

```
getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

in your `DialogFragment`'s `onCreateView`

Comment: you might also want to remove half transparent black background (dimming), check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33800422/2115904

Comment: Tends to make more sense when written as: `getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));`

Comment: Removes all margins as well.. Dialog is expanded to full width.

Comment: And it will cause an exception: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window android.app.Dialog.getWindow()' on a null object reference`.

Comment: Also you can call `getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);` instead. In order this not to invoke an exception you should call a `DialogFragment` from Activity or Fragment through `dialogFragment.show(...);` method, not FragmentTransaction's `add`.

Comment: In case someone is looking for the Kotlin snippet, here it is: `dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))`.

Comment: @UdayadityaBarua  encounter dailog expended problem, is there workaround just to make dialog background transparent but not touch its margin?

Comment: Finally, `getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)` play the trick I needed. But notice that not to call on `onCreateDialog()`, maybe on `onResume()`, getDecorView() maybe null when too early

Answer (score 25):

Try this ([How to I create a 100% custom DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849719/how-to-i-create-a-100-custom-dialogfragment))
this work for dialog

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());

    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);      

        // layout to display
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_edit);

    // set color transpartent
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 17):

Set your theme like this worked for me

```
<style name="MyDialog" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

And in your dialog fragment set like this

```
public class Progress extends DialogFragment {


int style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE;
int theme = R.style.MyDialog;

public Progress() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(style, theme);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress, container, false);
}
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can achieve by adding this in 
**Dialog Fragment** or **BottomSheetDialogFragment**

In **`onCreateDialog` Method**

```
@Override
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
       dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
       dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
       dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
       return dialog;
   }
```

Comment: `setBackgroundDrawableResource` and `clearFlags` works for me (kotlin, android api v28)

Answer (score 12):

In `onActivityCreated`

```
getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes().alpha = 0.9f; // An alpha value to apply to this entire window. An alpha of 1.0 means fully opaque and 0.0 means fully transparent
```

for `DialogFragment` transparent

Answer (score 8):

For completely transparent use:
**setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);**

For custom background -create a style file in you values folder (values/style.xml) and use it:
**setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, yourpackagename.R.style.YOURE_CUSTOM_STYLE);**

in your style file override the atribute:
**android:windowBackground** to be **@color/DialogBackgroundBlackSemiTransparent**

Answer (score 6):

```
<style name="BaseDialogTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>


    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">.00</item>//this line is changed alpha from 1.0 to 0.0(full transparent) 

</style>



@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.BaseDialogTheme);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Those who are using AlertDialog builder in `onCreateDialog` instead of `onCreateView` can assign theme like following code. Complete set of themes can be found from [R.style](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html). Don't forget that some of them supported recently and are not available on old device phones.

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_album, null);
        builder.setView(view);

        return builder.create();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks,This is what I was searching for.

Answer (score 3):

Try this if you like to:

```
public TransparentDialog()
{
    super();
    setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.AppTheme);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Per accepted answer, in Kotlin

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    var v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
    return v
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me. Then I tried this and worked

**Created a style**

```
<style name="CustomBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/CustomBottomSheetStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomBottomSheetStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**Applied this style from onCreate:**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.CustomBottomSheetDialogTheme)
}
```

Comment: question is about dialog, not bottomSheet

Comment: Yes, though I named here bottomSheet, but also works with dialog. Behind the scene is, before, this theme I was using in my bottom sheet.