# How to create a DialogFragment transparent over a Activity android

Tags: android

I have a basic `DialogFragment` called from a Activity and I need to make it transparent so I put a `STYLE_NO_TITLE` on style so it could fill all the screen but its not working!

```
public class FabDialog extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_NoActionBar);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fab_layout,container,false);

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
```

}

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045556/cant-make-the-custom-dialogfragment-transparent-over-the-fragment

Comment: set Dialog Background to be transparent in `onCreateView` .add `getDialog().getWindow()..setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT))`

Comment: I tried this,s not working!