# AppCompatDialogFragment change background color

Tags: android, appcompatdialogfragment

How do I change the background color of `AppCompatDialogFragment`.

My class is extends `AppCompatDialogFragment` and I don't know how to change the property background color of all the dialog.

```
public class MyClassName extends AppCompatDialogFragment { ...}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same method posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045556/cant-make-the-custom-dialogfragment-transparent-over-the-fragment) about making the background transparent and change transparent to color.

Create `onCreateView` and inside add the following line: `getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW));`

Change `Color.YELLOW` to the background color that you want.

Full example:

```
public class ClassName extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
    ...
    ...
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW));
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

If you want color from colors resources use:

```
getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getContext().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)));
```

Were `colorPrimary` is color resources name.